# Lua in iOS and side-loading scripts

Tags: ios, lua

The latest game by Gameloft called Order&Chaos starts with a *Checking for Update* screen, which indicates that they're able to update certain data without updating the entire binary.

[image]

I'm quite certain that they're using some kind of scripting language like Lua in their app and updating these scripts to e.g. change certain values (like buying price of items).

What's your experience with side-loading or updating scripts in your iOS application?
I don't mean loading new graphics or other contents, but game logic like my path finding implementation in Lua.

Apple cleary states that this isn't allowed

> 3.3.2 An Application may not download or install executable code.
>   Interpreted code may only be used in
>   an Application if all scripts, code
>   and interpreters are packaged in the
>   Application and not downloaded. The
>   only exception to the foregoing is
>   scripts and code downloaded and run by
>   Apple's built-in WebKit framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens in most of these applications TinyChef, RestaurantStory, HotelStory, etc..

They update content, but not the core program. Just adds new content or modifies the existing using external files and DB updates from a remote server.

Example, what they do is download new graphics and add a new item to their Desserts table of their DB and finally when they show all their Desserts the new one shows up and its ready to be cooked as if it was in the app from the beginning.

I could elaborate more info if you need.

**UPDATE**

If you are using lua, you could easily add, say new levels to your games, just by downloading a file containing your level data. Im sure that you are familiar with using external files one per level/item/character with a common format you then parse in your app.

You can have your path finding algorithm in another file as i said, and update (download and replace) that unique file whenever you improve it.

Comment: yap, the basics of data driven design. I wasn't clear that I meant the game logic.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, yet, but wouldn't it be as easy as querying a server, getting back a string, then parsing that into the database?

That might not violate Apples policy, since it wouldn't be executable code, just delimited text.

You could probably do more complicated stuff that way too. It wouldn't be a whole lot different than DropBox downloading files to your phone so you can view them. But instead of a document file, it would be a 3D object.

Comment: yep, that's not the problem ;) but it would be great to update some of my game logic, which I implemented in Lua without updating the entire app.

Answer (score 1):

I think 3.3.2 clausule is to prevent that anyone can download/buy from appStore an engine like Love2D for iPhone, create games/apps in Lua, download it on the iPhone via web and execute with this engine, because it means develop and deploy apps on iPhone using an intermediate SDK instead of the official SDK, and of course, without paying anything to Apple.

Think about it, you can create your own App Store with this system and that is what Apple wants to prevent. but i think Apple doesn't take care of this type of downloads, where you want to update your own apps logic or levels.